# How to import an interface from @types in index.d.ts?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Express exposes `Express.Request`, `Express.Response` but I also need `Express.NextFunction` interface which is not available in the Express namespace.

How to use the `NextFunction` interface in index.d.ts?

Context:

- `index.d.ts` declares a namespace **ServerPlugin**.
- ServerPlugin contains an interface called **Params**
- Anywhere in the app, I can use `ServerPlugin.Params` as expected

But, as soon as I import NextFunction from [@types/express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express), in `index.d.ts` I get errors in all files using `ServerPlugin.Params`.

> Cannot find namespace 'ServerPlugin'

**index.d.ts**

If not importing `NextFunction` and commenting out `next` => no error

```ts
declare namespace ServerPlugin {
    interface Params {
        req: Express.Response;
        res: Express.Request;
        next: NextFunction;
        options: object;
        // ... and much more
    }
}

import { NextFunction } from 'express';
```

**user.ts**

This file says it cannot find namespace ServerPlugin.

If I `import { ServerPlugin } from '../../index'`, no error, but I did not have to import before using NextFunction.

```ts
import { userViewerChunk } from './graphql/UserType';

const user: Function = ({ next, extendSchema }: ServerPlugin.Params): void => {
    extendSchema(userViewerChunk);
    next();
};

export default user;
```

Comment: I'm not following your problem here.  Your `index.d.ts` example seems to compile fine, and I have no problem mixing an import of `ServerPlugin` from `index.d.ts` and importing `NextFunction` from `express`.  Can you at least show the compiler error you're getting?

Comment: I just solved the issue by renaming index.d.ts to global.d.ts. Do you think the issue occured because I had a index.ts at the same level as index.d.ts? index.ts was just exporting all undelying modules.

Comment: Yes, typescript has a fuzzy logic for matching imports.  If you run `tsc --traceResolution` it will give you extremely verbose output about what filenames it tries and in what order.  See http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-typescript-resolves-modules for the official documentation.  If you give it a name like `import x from "abc"` it searches a bunch of extension patterns (defined in the link above) until it finds the first match.  Specifically, `.ts` is searched before `.d.ts`, so that would cause your problem.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, much appreciated. Please feel free to extend your comment as an answer so I can select it as the answer and upvote.